# Cannot connect SFTP with FileZilla

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04, cloud, ftp

I have OpenStack Havana installed in Ubuntu 12.04.4 Server.

I have successfully launched a Ubuntu Cloud image's instance in OpenStack.

I can successfully ping/SSH to my instance via my OpenStack's host, that is Ubuntu 12.04.4 Server.

What I want is that to upload files to **Ubuntu instance** from my OpenStack's host using FileZilla (I know it supports SFTP).

When I try to connect it says:

```
Connection timed out
```

Note: - **FileZilla is installed on my Ubuntu which is hosting my OpenStack and I can successfully SSH to my instance from here**

Comment: Add your logs /var/log/secure.log from your instance. Are you sure to set the right port 22 on filezilla when you try to connect ? Did you try with another sftp client ?

Comment: Port is 22 and protocol is set to SFTP.

Comment: Can you show your sshd_config file to check if the sftp-server subsystem is unable ? What about the test with another sftp client (like lftp) than filezilla ?